# Opening pdf in browser from link

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link as such

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ str_replace(Request::path(), '', Request::url()) . $finalsHistory->file_path }}"> 
  <img src="{{ str_replace(Request::path(), '', Request::url()) . $finalsHistory->thumbnail_path}}" alt="cover final"/>
</a>
```

and  I'm trying to make it so that the pdf does not download, but instead opens in a browser window, preferably a new tab.

Is there anyway to do this? As you can see I've already tried `target='_blank'`, but that just doesn't seem to be working. Is it possible to do this in html or do I need to accomplish this with jQuery?

Edit: This is the full link

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost:8000/uploads/1/finals/printed_books/paperback/4569_text_2013-10-29_8-45-51_1383050752.pdf"><img src="http://localhost:8000/assets/img/pdfImg.png" alt="cover final"></a>
```

Comment: `target='_blank'` is suppose to open a new tab, did you try it with other browsers? Because it may also be a browser problem

Comment: I've tried it in safari, chrome and firefox. And it's fine if it opens in a new tab (actually the best possible solution)...I just don't want it to automatically download.

Comment: Generally speaking, when you click on a file link, it displays that link in the browser. Can you give us the site containing this so we can try it as well?

Comment: I do not have a live version of this. Its an internal project for the company I'm working for.

Comment: the download mechanism is embedded into the browser's program, but to my understanding, your code shouldn't be triggering the download... maybe you should provide a link?

Comment: @DanielCheung When I use other websites I can view pdf files from links just fine. And I know there is a way to do this, but all the research I have done has come to no help. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you provide us with the link created from "{{ str_replace(Request::path(), '', Request::url()) . $finalsHistory->file_path }}" ?

Comment: @JoelWorsham Just updated the original question with the link

Comment: can you try `target='_tab'`, it is not supported by all browsers, but try if it works

Comment: @DanielCheung It opens a new blank tab, but then the pdf just downloads.

Comment: this is not really possible, but do you reckon because it is on localhost? because a few mechanism breaks working on localhost and I tried using _blank before and it worked

Comment: @DanielCheung I don't really see how being on localhost would affect it. You've tried _blank on localhost and it worked before?

Comment: The link does look valid. My limited knowledge would also lead me to believe the localhost could processing the request differently than it would on a server (@Daniel Cheung)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking at the HTML code, you can only influence the browser behavior by setting the response-headers of the server. How the server delivers these PDFs is important to how the browser does handle them, like opening them inline or downloading them directly.

PDFs should be delivered with `Content-Type: application/pdf` to allow browsers displaying it. Other header settings such as `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` or `Content-Disposition: attachment` will enforce a download of the file.

If you are using Apache you can set these parameters in a `.htaccess` file for example. But still that's just a recommendation for what the browser should do.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly, to make a pdf open in the browser at all I have to set Content-Type: application/pdf in the htaccess? How come on sites like freechristianpublishing.com I can open a pdf in the browser just fine and did not have to edit the .htaccess to accomplish it?

Comment: That depends a lot on the default settings the server comes with and which components are installed. Given that you asked for a localhost project I am quite sure that the actual server has different settings.

Comment: So using the answer you gave...how would this fix my issue?

Comment: I am not sure, if I get this right: Are you also running the site mentioned in your comment?
If yes then it probably was already set correctly. But you can't edit other websites' server config.

Comment: The site I mentioned in my comment works fine, my local one does not. And nothing I seem to do fixes it even though it has the same settings and same code. And why would I ever want to edit another websites server config? I'm not a hacker...well that often...